# Plot numpy arrays in column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = 

sample_type         observed_data
     A          [0.2, 0.5, 0.17, 0.1]
     A          [0.9, 0.3, 0.24, 0.5]
     A          [0.9, 0.5, 0.6, 0.39]
```

where the data type in the `observed_data` column is `np.array`. How could I plot each individual np.array as a separate function to compare the trajectories of the observed data across samples of type 'A'? In addition, is there a quick way I can compute the average across all rows in the `observed_data` column to plot the average, as well? So I average across the three rows in `observed_data` to get a final array of `avg = [0.666, 0.433, 0.336, 0.33]`?

Comment: Can you explain what does it exactly mean by *How could I plot each individual np.array as a separate function to compare the trajectories of the observed data* ?

Comment: For your second question, you can try `np.mean(df['observed_data'].to_numpy, axis=0)`

Comment: @ThePyGuy How can I plot the values in each row under the column `observed_data'?

Comment: @ThePyGuy I'm trying to plot the values in each of the three rows on a graph . Should I do a for-loop over the rows in `df['observed_data']`?

Comment: @MAsoccer9 Manually looping in pandas and numpy is always a bad idea, you should look for vectorized operation. And I suggest you to edit the question and add some code for the plot you are interested in using the data you've added in the question.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I'm mainly just asking how I can plot a line plot for each of the numpy arrays in the rows. The end goal is a plot with each numpy array line plot overlayed on one another. Does that require using `np.vectorize`?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to calculate the mean is to call `mean()` on underlying numpy array of the Pandas column, as you need to calculate mean on column levels for the column with numpy arrays in them:

```py
>> df['observed_data'].values.mean()

array([0.66666667, 0.43333333, 0.33666667, 0.33      ])
```

And by plotting numpy arrays to a function, if you mean to say passing them to a function, you can call `apply` and pass the function:

```py
# Mean for each numpy arrays in the column:
df['observed_data'].apply(np.mean)

0    0.2425
1    0.4850
2    0.5975
Name: observed_data, dtype: float64
```